# Why I get error while creating IPA for iOS having Vuforia SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I have released many enterprise builds for my project and for new version, I have used Vuforia SDK for AR functionality. While I am creating Enterprise build with Distribution certificate and profile (by which I have released many versions), I cannot able to generate IPA and getting following error in Xcode:

[image]

I had copied `Vuforia.framework` from their demo provided and used it's functionality in my existing project and all is working fine in iPad.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Is the Vuforia framework provided with bitcode enabled?  If not you will need to disable bitcode throughout your project

Comment: Can I disable bitcode while creating build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled `bitcode` and it could create a build without any issue.